# Should I create a function that filters and returns a mutated copy of the filtered values?

Tags: naming

Say I have a function whose input is an array of `fruit` objects, and returns a list of *cloned) apples from that list, with each cloned apple mutated with an additional property `visible` on it.  Would a good name be `extractApplesAndSetVisibility`, or is there a better name?

Comment: Do you have a single reason you are doing these two things?  What is that single reason?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't. The fact that you used the word "and" both in your description of what the function does and even in the name of the function strongly suggests that your function is not doing one thing. It is doing two things, one thing *and* another thing.

If you split it into two functions, then your naming problem is solved, because both of the functions already have standardized names (in fact, you probably won't have to name them at all, because both of them are very likely to already exist in your language's core or standard libraries).

A function that filters a collection is usually called `filter`, also sometimes `select` (Smalltalk, Ruby), `where` (SQL, XQuery, LINQ), `find_all` (Ruby); in Relational Algebra it is called a *Selection* or *Restriction*. A function that transforms elements of a collection is usually called `map`, also sometimes `collect` (Smalltalk, Ruby), `transform` (C++), `select` (SQL, XQuery, LINQ); in Relational Algebra it is called a *Projection*.